# Prevent button effect on html input and button tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm writing an intranet MVC application and want all of the buttons to look and act the same way. For some actions like Create, Details, Back to List I use the GET method and for Create and Save I use the POST method.

I make a little CSS so the button, a and input tags looks the same way:

```
input[type="submit"].actionButton,
button[type="submit"].actionButton,
a.actionButton,
a.actionButton:visited {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

But both the input and button tag have an effect for mouse down event. How can I prevent that? The best solution would be via CSS but I haven't yet determined the target browser. Mostly IE7 and IE8.

A javascript solution to this problem would be fine too.

Thanks,
Péter

Comment: Are you searching for `:focus` selector?

Comment: `:active { padding: -1px 0 0 -1px; }` ?

Comment: I can see a.actionButton:visited but not a.actionButton:active? Maybe that solves it?

Comment: @Silvermind Could you post your answer as Asnwer not comment? I would like to set as accepted answer :)

Comment: @Péter Added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of a button in IE.
This can be 'undone' (tricked) by adding a negative padding to the button on `:active`

```
input[type="submit"]:active,
button[type="submit"]:active {
    padding: -1px 0 0 -1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
input[type="submit"].actionButton:active,
button[type="submit"].actionButton:active,
```